# Generate word list based on Spanish text file

Tags: strings, ruby, sorting

I'm a beginner and wrote a program that takes a text file and writes a downcased vocabulary list to another text file. I intend to use it mainly to work with text in Spanish, so I added a line to downcase capitalized-accented words. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of reading from the original file, as well as removing non-letters and sorting for unique items.

```
f = File.open("/.../quijote.txt")
words = f.read.split.map(&:downcase)
f.close

#remove numbers and non-letters
words = words.map {|item| item.tr('0-9.,;:¿¡?!«»\‘\“\”\–\]\[\-\(\)\'\"', '')}

#downcase capitalized accented words
words = words.map {|item| item.tr('ÁÉÍÓÚÑ', 'áéíóúñ')}

words = words.uniq.sort

# write each word on a separate line in the file...
File.open("/.../quijotewords.txt", "w+") do |f|
  words.each { |element| f.puts(element) }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- `open` + `read` + `close`: Better to use the block form: `contents = File.open(path) { |fd| fd.read  }` or simply `contents = File.read(path)`
- `words = words.something`: Don't re-use variable names. New values, new names. For example: `sorted_words = words.sort`.
- Use `File.write`
- Instead of removing chars that you don't want, I'd remove the chars that you *do* want.
- You can apply the processing to the whole file or line and then split.
- `string.tr(something, '')` -> `string.delete(something)`.

I'd write:

```
words = File.read("quijote.txt").downcase.
  tr("ÁÉÍÓÚÑ", "áéíóúñ").delete("^[a-z]áéíóúüñ \n").
  split.uniq.sort
File.write("quijote-words.txt", words.join("\n"))
```

If your input file is not UTF8-encoded but, let's say, ISO8859-15, you'd write: `File.read("quijote.txt", encoding: "iso8859-15").encode("utf-8")`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for some of my files, but for others I'm getting `rb:2:in downcase': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)` I read that ruby does sometimes. Is there a way around it given your suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Based on @tokland code.
No need to join array with newline symbol -- `#puts` does that for you silently:

```
File.open("quijote-words.txt", "w") do |file|
  file.puts File.read("quijote.txt").
    downcase.tr("ÁÉÍÓÚÑ", "áéíóúñ").
    delete("^[a-z]áéíóúüñ \n").split.uniq.sort
end
```

Comment: This is nice and compact. However, note a subtle change in behaviour: if it fails to open `quijote.txt`, it will still have clobbered `quijote-words.txt` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bug: any numbers in the text would initially be classified as a word, then its digits and decimal point would be discarded, leaving an empty word to be written to the result.  I recommend converting the garbage characters into spaces before word-splitting.  (You can even coalesce the two `tr` calls into one.)

`f.close` is rarely desirable.  A less error-prone approach is to call `File.open` with a block, like you did at the end.  Here, you wouldn't even need a block to read the file: just call `File.read`.

You can avoid a lot of calls to `words.map` if you postpone the `split`.  If you do need to use `map` or `each`, avoid using `|item|` or `|element|` as block parameter names; prefer a meaningful name like `|word|` instead.

```
words = File.read('/.../quijote.txt')
  .tr('ÁÉÍÓÚÑ0-9.,;:¿¡?!«»\‘\“\”\–\]\[\-\(\)\'\"', 'áéíóúñ ')
  .downcase
  .split
  .uniq
  .sort

File.open('/.../quijotewords.txt', 'w+') do |f|
  f.puts(words)
end
```

Listing `'ÁÉÍÓÚÑ'` as special cases is a hack, though.  You should probably use a [proper library](//stackoverflow.com/q/1910573/1157100) to perform internationalization-sensitive `downcase`.  Similarly, stripping punctuation would be better done using `gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, ' ')`.